# Get information about a url in terminal

Tags: dns, url

There's this useful command that gets information about a server when you pass it a url that's pointed at the server in question.

I can't remember it though, or find it. It gets the OS of the server, the webserver installed on it and more useful information. I think it might be `curl`, but what options should I pass it?

Is there an app I can `apt-get` that will provide even more information about a url that isn't offered by this native application I can't find?

I'm trying to scan a server for ports and that sort of thing. Just want a breif overview. It wasn't nmap. It instantly returned

```
Webserver :
OS :
```

Information like that.

Comment: what type of information I wonder ?

Answer (score 0):

`wget -qS -O- http://www.website.tld:portnumber` will deliver the information to you directly for you to analyze and nmap will inspect the headers coming from a server with the command `nmap -A -T4 www.website.tld` (replace **website.tld** with the website you wish to study) and try to *guess* at what's running there. curl is less forthcoming, but if you do `curl http://192.168.1.2:portnumber` the last line returned will tell you which protocol a port expects.

The sysadmin of that site can block or provide misleading information, though, to make it tougher for script kiddies to perform attacks-from-a-can.